# DAX formula for all Customer Orders older than 60 days

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

Table contain columns like: (Customer_Id, Customer_Name, Customer_Category, Last_Order_Date)
I need in PowerBI, DAX formula to show all customers which order is older than 60 days from today's date.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset and the desired output in tabular form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure = COUNTROWS(FILTER('BC Customer', DATEDIFF([Last_Order_Date], TODAY(), DAY) > 60))